# Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type - FirebaseUI

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I do not understand what the problem is, according to me everything is working correctly.

Logcat:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.hamidmadarati.mobilsorgulari.Home.Dashboard.ui.PassengerRecyclerModel
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(CustomClassMapper.java:436)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(CustomClassMapper.java:232)
> at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(CustomClassMapper.java:80)
> at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(DataSnapshot.java:203)

Fragment:

```
public class PassengerFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView listVehiclesWeekDay;
    private FirebaseRecyclerOptions<PassengerRecyclerModel> options;
    private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PassengerRecyclerModel, PassengerMyViewHolderRecycler> adapter;
    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_passenger, container,false);

        listVehiclesWeekDay = view.findViewById(R.id.listVehiclesWeekDay);
        listVehiclesWeekDay.setHasFixedSize(true);
        listVehiclesWeekDay.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Travels").child("DaysOfTheWeekSimple");
        options = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder<PassengerRecyclerModel>().setQuery(databaseReference, PassengerRecyclerModel.class).build();
        adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<PassengerRecyclerModel, PassengerMyViewHolderRecycler>(options){
            @Override
            protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PassengerMyViewHolderRecycler holder, int position, @NonNull PassengerRecyclerModel model) {
                if (model.getDay() != null){
                    holder.titleTextView.setText(model.getDay());
                }
            }
            @Override
            public PassengerMyViewHolderRecycler onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerow, parent, false);
                return new PassengerMyViewHolderRecycler(view);
            }
        };
        adapter.startListening();
        listVehiclesWeekDay.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
        listVehiclesWeekDay.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return view;
    }
}
```

Class:

```
public class PassengerRecyclerModel {
    private String day; //name

    public PassengerRecyclerModel() {
        //Empty - for Firebase Database
    }

    // model
    public PassengerRecyclerModel(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }

    //Getter and Setter
    public String getDay() {
        return day;
    }
    public void setDay(String day) {
        this.day = day;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, please edit your question and add your code in text format rather than screenshots.

Comment: I have a problem with converting an object to a string with a firebase class, the code is already appended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are passing the following reference:

```
databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Travels").child("DaysOfTheWeekSimple");
```

Along with "PassengerRecyclerModel" class to FirebaseRecyclerOptions.Builder's "setQuety()" method, means that you want to use the Firebase-UI library for displaying all "PassengerRecyclerModel" objects that exist within:

```
Travels -> DaysOfTheWeekSimple
```

Which actually is not possible, since under that reference it exists only a child of type String, hence the following error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Can't convert object of type java.lang.String to type com.hamidmadarati.mobilsorgulari.Home.Dashboard.ui.PassengerRecyclerModel
```

To solve this, you need to add an extra level under your "DaysOfTheWeekSimple" node. That can be simply achieved using the DatabaseReference's [push()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference#push()) method. So when you are adding an object at the above reference, add it like this:

```
databaseReference.push().setValue(passengerRecyclerModel);
```

In this way, you database schema should look like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- Travels
       |
       --- DaysOfTheWeekSimple
             |
             --- $pushedId
                   |
                   --- day: "Day 5: 22-4-2021"
```

The code for getting the data may remain unchanged.

**Edit:**

According to your comments:

> Nope, in fact, we do not create data

If you add the data directly in the Firebase Console, you won't be able to use push(). If you don't want to add data programmatically, the extra level of a layer is still required. So in that case, between the "DaysOfTheWeekSimple" node and the "day" property, add another node with at least a date, or an Id, like this:

```
Firebase-root
  |
  --- Travels
       |
       --- DaysOfTheWeekSimple
             |
             --- 22-4-2021 //Extra level added
                   |
                   --- day: "Day 5: 22-4-2021"
```

> the problem is when it is obtained and firebase thinks it is an object and does not convert it to a string

Doesn't "think", the object is of type "PassengerRecyclerModel" and should be read accordingly in the adapter.

Comment: In the exact same section you already have the addition operation of the object, right?

Comment: This is the code that generates errors, in which part of the code do I add this push? PD:Thanks! https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAwT3.png

Comment: How do you add data to the database? Where in the code are you using setValue()? That code should be replaced, otherwise, your actual code will continue to yield errors.

Comment: Nope, in fact we do not create data, but we get it to show it, the problem is when it is obtained and firebase thinks it is an object and does not convert it to a string

Comment: Please check my updated answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: Ok, give it a try and tell me if it works.

Comment: It turned out that the error was the reference, your solution is correct, you have to add an extra value, a push to make it work and not crash when it gets the data, thanks